# Yocto: dedicated recipe only to create an SDK

Tags: sdk, yocto, yocto-recipe

To create an SDK with Bitbake/Yocto, the regular way is to call the `populate_sdk` task on the image recipe, like that:

```
 bitbake -c populate_sdk my-image
```

For a special purpose, I would like to create a little recipe that will never be used to build an entire image, but only one customized SDK. I would like to explicitly name the components and libraries that I are part of it.

Is that possible? I imagine directly inheriting `populate_sdk.bbclass`. But then, how can I specify packages that are part of the SDK, if I don't have the `IMAGE_INSTALL` variable? Can anyone provide a minimal example of an "SDK-only recipe"?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the meta-toolchain recipe as this does something similar.